# Invite guests to yammer home network through API

Tags: yammer

I understand that with the API we can invite users to a home or external network.

Does someone know if there is any restriction with inviting guests through the API ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the current user is a verified admin in a paid yammer network, users with external email domains can be added. If the current user is not, only email addresses for official company domains will be allowed."

From the official documentation. https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/invitationsjson

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the 'or external network' part of the question, because there's no way to specify which network you want the invites to be sent for. The invites will only be sent for the requesting user's home network.